# Regular Expressions Using Python's Re

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file full of lines similar to this:

line = 'Weclome - MIsiti International,0,0,-9,0,'

I want to replace `'Weclome - MIsiti International'` with the string `'1'`

here is my code:

```
exp=re.compile(r"([\./A-Za-z\s\-]+)")
print exp.sub("1",line)
```

Unfortunately I get the following output:

```
1,0,0,19,0,
```

Which is incorrect. i thought this would work:

```
exp=re.compile(r"([\./A-Za-z\s\-[^0-9]]+)")
print exp.sub("1",line)
```

But it does not:

```
[]
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to use negative lookahead to solve the hyphen problem? I gave it a try but didn't manage to get it to work.

Comment: Your first regex is doing exactly what you say you want (i.e. replacing: `'Weclome - MIsiti International'` with the string `"1"`). Can you please be more explicit in what you really want it to do?

Comment: @ridgerunner His regex is OK to replace the first part, but it also replaces **'-9'** with **'19'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes cannot be nested. The later example will eat '[', '^', etc. Would it not work if you simply did r"(^[^,0-9]+)", i.e. anything at the start not being commaor 0-9?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a regular expression?

```
>>> line = 'Weclome - MIsiti International,0,0,-9,0,'
>>> s=line.split(",")
>>> s[0]="1"
>>> ','.join(s)
'1,0,0,-9,0,'
```

Comment: No you don't _need_ to use regex. But the regex solution can fix an entire file full of lines in one operation. (I'd be curious to see which is quicker?)

Comment: Here's an idea that uses regex, but not exclusively: `line = ','.join(map(lambda x: x if re.match(r"\d") else '1', line.split(',')))`

Comment: @ridgerunner, so can normal string operations.

Comment: @Chris, maybe you should post that as your own answer.

Comment: interesting.  originally tried spit but didnt realize "join" was the solution. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
exp=re.compile(r"([\./A-Za-z\s\-]+)"
```

No need to put **'\'** before **'-'** between brackets. Put **'-'** at a place between brackets where it can't have its special meaning.

Also, no need to put **'\'** before the dot **'.'** between brackets because a dot between brackets looses its special meaning.

So, instead of `exp=re.compile(r"([\./A-Za-z\s\-]+)")` , write `exp=re.compile(r"([./A-Za-z\s-]+)")`

.

Concerning `exp=re.compile(r"([\./A-Za-z\s\-[^0-9]]+)")` , it doesn't match at all because  it is the same for **'['**  than for **'-'** : if placed in a position where it can't have a meaning, then it looses its special meaning and is considered simply as the character.

So the **'['** before `'^0-9]'` is the bracket, not the beginninge of a class. Consequently, the **']'** at the end of `'^0-9]'` is the ending bracket of the first left bracket in `'[\./A-Z...'` AND the last right bracket followed by '+' means *"the character ] at least one time and possibly more"*

.

```
import re

line = 'Weclome - MIsiti International,0,0,-9,0,'

exp=re.compile(r"(^[./A-Za-z\s-]+)")
print exp.sub("1",line)

# or

exp=re.compile(r"([./A-Za-z\s-]+(?=,))")
print exp.sub("1",line)
```

result

```
1,0,0,-9,0,
1,0,0,-9,0,
```

Answer (score 0):

You're first regex is good but you need to anchor it to the beginning of the line and add the 'm' multiline modifier like so:

```py
import re
line = 'Weclome - MIsiti International,0,0,-9,0,'
exp = re.compile(r"^([./A-Za-z\s\-]+)", re.M)
print (exp.sub("1",line))
```

Note that this solution fixes an entire file full of lines in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

Most people are giving you answers `<snark>`often qualified with "Don't use regex! Regex is evil and comes from Perl! We Python users have trancended mere text manipulation!"`</snark>` but no one is explaining why you're experiencing this problem.

Your regex is working. It takes any alphabet, whitespace, or hyphen character and turns it into the number `1`. The problem is that it thinks the negative sign in `-9` is "evil text" to turn into a number.

One way to approach this is to provide an anchor for your regex - Make it match the commas (or beginning/ending of the string) surrounding the text. So it would see `,text,` and turn it into `,1,` but would see `,-9,` and know that it's not text.

Another approach is to filter based on "does it *not* contain digits" instead of "does it contain these things I need" - because what if, later, you need to filter out other punctuation marks? Using `,[^0-9,]+,` would match "things that aren't digits or commas", which would turn `,text,` into `,1,` but keep `,-9,` the same.

A third approach is to split the string on commas, then test and change each individual segment - probably to see if it contains digits - and then join them back together.

If you choose the first or second approaches, I leave it up to you to write a regex that either matches a leading comma *or* the beginning of a string (and a trailing comma *or* the end of the string - both are similar). It's not terribly difficult.

Comment: -1: I don't see *"Most people are giving you answers <snark>often qualified with "Don't use regex! Regex is evil and comes from Perl! We Python users have trancended mere text manipulation!"</snark>"* (At the moment there are 4 other answers: which 3 answers do you mean?)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian - I was being silly. I thought the `<snark>` implied humor and sarcasm.

Comment: ok, I didn't recognized it without explicit `#NotIntendedToBeAFactualStatement`